# How to remove the time in my Date column when printing

Tags: vb.net, printing, datagridview

i have a program that print a datagridview and have a date column in it.

the column display date only but when i try to print it, it will have time add how can i remove it?

this is how it looks in the datagridview

[image]

and this is my printpreview

[image]

print code

```
        Try
            dgvInventoryLog.Columns(6).DefaultCellStyle.Format = "dd/MM/yyyy"

            Dim actualWidth As Integer = dgvInventoryLog.Columns.Cast(Of DataGridViewColumn).Sum(Function(c) c.Width)
            Dim percentage As Decimal = CDec(((100 / actualWidth) * e.MarginBounds.Width) / 100)
            Dim header As String = "Inventory Log"
            Dim footer As String
            Dim startX As Integer = e.MarginBounds.Left
            Dim startY As Integer = e.MarginBounds.Top
            Dim r As Rectangle

            Dim headerFont As New Font(dgvInventoryLog.Font.FontFamily, 15, FontStyle.Italic, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)
            Dim szf As SizeF = e.Graphics.MeasureString(header, headerFont)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(header, headerFont, Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left + (e.MarginBounds.Width - szf.Width) / 2, startY - szf.Height)
            footer = "Page " & pageCounter.ToString
            szf = e.Graphics.MeasureString(footer, headerFont)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(footer, headerFont, Brushes.Black, e.MarginBounds.Left + (e.MarginBounds.Width - szf.Width) / 2, e.MarginBounds.Bottom + 5)

            startY += 5

            'this is the text alignment
            Dim sf As New StringFormat
            sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center
            sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center

            Dim gridFont As New Font(dgvInventoryLog.Font.FontFamily, dgvInventoryLog.Font.Size, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel)

            ' If startRow = 0 Then
            For x As Integer = 0 To dgvInventoryLog.Columns.Count - 1
                    r.X = startX
                    r.Y = startY
                    r.Width = CInt(dgvInventoryLog.Columns(x).Width * percentage)
                    r.Height = dgvInventoryLog.Rows(0).Height
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, r)
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(dgvInventoryLog.Columns(x).HeaderText, gridFont, Brushes.Black, r, sf)
                    startX += r.Width
                Next

                startY += r.Height
            ' End If

            For y As Integer = startRow To dgvInventoryLog.Rows.Count - 1
                If y = dgvInventoryLog.NewRowIndex Then Continue For
                startX = e.MarginBounds.Left
                For x As Integer = 0 To dgvInventoryLog.Columns.Count - 1
                    r.X = startX
                    r.Y = startY
                    r.Width = CInt(dgvInventoryLog.Columns(x).Width * percentage)
                    r.Height = dgvInventoryLog.Rows(0).Height
                    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, r)
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(If(Not dgvInventoryLog.Rows(y).Cells(x).Value Is Nothing, dgvInventoryLog.Rows(y).Cells(x).Value.ToString, ""),
                                            gridFont, Brushes.Black, r, sf)

                    startX += r.Width
                Next
                startY += r.Height
                If startY >= e.MarginBounds.Bottom - 10 Then
                    If y < dgvInventoryLog.Rows.Count - 1 Then
                        e.HasMorePages = True
                        pageCounter += 1
                        startRow = y + 1
                        Exit For
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub

Private Sub btnPrint_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnPrint.Click
        ''preview button
        pageCounter = 1
        startRow = 0
        ppd.Document = pd
        ppd.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
        ppd.ShowDialog()
    End Sub
```

```
Private Sub getInventoryLog()
        Using conn As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\INVENTORY_DB.accdb")
            Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand("Select ItemCode as [ITEM CODE], ItemName AS [ITEM NAME], Description AS [DESCRIPTION], Price AS [PRICE],
                                         Unit AS [UNIT], Quantity AS [QUANTITY], MovementDate AS [MOVEMENT DATE], `From` AS [FROM],
                                         `To` AS [TO] From [Items Movement]", conn)
            Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter
            Dim dt As New DataTable
            da.SelectCommand = cmd
            dt.Clear()
            da.Fill(dt)
            dgvInventoryLog.Columns.Clear()
            dgvInventoryLog.DataSource = dt

            dgvInventoryLog.Columns(0).Width = 80
            dgvInventoryLog.Columns(1).Width = 250
            dgvInventoryLog.Columns(2).Width = 150
            dgvInventoryLog.Columns(3).Width = 70
            dgvInventoryLog.Columns(4).Width = 70
            dgvInventoryLog.Columns(5).Width = 100
            dgvInventoryLog.Columns(6).Width = 110
            dgvInventoryLog.Columns(7).Width = 135
            dgvInventoryLog.Columns(8).Width = 135

        End Using
    End Sub
```

this is where i get the code for printing. i dont quite understand it, but its working just fine so i just copy paste it, so if that is where i messed up i will be grateful for pointing it out for me. thanks

https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?872037-RESOLVED-Need-help-with-printing-datagridview-content

Comment: Draw the [FormattedValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell.formattedvalue?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) instead...  `dgvInventoryLog.Rows(y).Cells(x).FormattedValue`

Comment: e.Graphics.DrawString(If(Not dgvInventoryLog.Rows(y).Cells(x).FormattedValue Is Nothing, dgvInventoryLog.Rows(y).Cells(x).Value.ToString, ""),
                                            gridFont, Brushes.Black, r, sf) is this what you mean?, i tried it but it`s not working

Comment: No, you `Nothing` check the `.FormattedValue` then draw the `.Value`. Just `e.Graphics.DrawString(dgvInventoryLog.Rows(y).Cells(x).FormattedValue, gridFont, Brushes.Black, r, sf)`. You don't need `Nothing` check here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your loop, check if it's the 7th column (index 6), then convert the value to date and format it as you wish

```
            For x As Integer = 0 To dgvInventoryLog.Columns.Count - 1
                r.X = startX
                r.Y = startY
                r.Width = CInt(dgvInventoryLog.Columns(x).Width * percentage)
                r.Height = dgvInventoryLog.Rows(0).Height
                e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(Pens.Black, r)
                If x = 6 Then
                   Dim movementDate As Date = Ctype(dgvInventoryLog.Rows(y).Cells(x).Value, Date)
                   e.Graphics.DrawString(movementDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"),
                                        gridFont, Brushes.Black, r, sf)
                   ' or dd/MM/yyyy
                Else
                   e.Graphics.DrawString(If(Not dgvInventoryLog.Rows(y).Cells(x).Value Is Nothing, dgvInventoryLog.Rows(y).Cells(x).Value.ToString, ""),
                                        gridFont, Brushes.Black, r, sf)
                End If


                startX += r.Width
            Next
```

Comment: this answer my question thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can make it so that the printing code respects the formatting in all columns, regardless of data type.

```vb
Dim value = dgvInventoryLog.Rows(y).Cells(x).Value
Dim format = dgvInventoryLog.Columns(x).DefaultCellStyle.Format
Dim text = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(format),
              value.ToString(),
              String.Format($"{{0:{format}}}", value))

e.Graphics.DrawString(text, gridFont, Brushes.Black, r, sf)
```

That will work for any type and any legitimate format and it will also work with empty cells, whether they contain `Nothing` or `DBNull.Value`. What gets printed will be the same as what is displayed in the grid regardless.

This bit:

```vb
String.Format($"{{0:{format}}}", value)
```

might look a bit weird, so let me explain. The `$` indicates string interpolation. Anything wrapped in braces within that interpolated string is evaluated and replaced with the result, with literal braces escaped with another brace. If, for instance, `format` contained `"dd/MM/yyyy"`, `$"{{0:{format}}}"` would produce `"{0:dd/MM/yyyy}"`. When that gets passed to `String.Format`, it is replaced with the contents of `value` in the specified format.

EDIT:

Note that, if you prefer, this:

```vb
Dim text = If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(format),
              value.ToString(),
              String.Format($"{{0:{format}}}", value))
```

could be replaced with this:

```vb
Dim text = String.Format(If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(format),
                            "{0}",
                            $"{{0:{format}}}"),
                         value)
```